# vb.net CreateObject vs direct reference using New

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a large .net solution that has a lot of projects in it. 
My question is, when referencing one project from another, is it better to do this:

```
Dim objSomething As Project.Class1 = Nothing 
objSomething = CreateObject("Project.Class1") 
...
```

Or simply:

```
Dim objSomething As New Project.Class1()
...
```

Also, is there a performance hit on one over the other?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Using COM to create a .NET object from a .NET program is never a good idea.

Comment: This project was written a LONG time ago (VB6) and migrated to .NET. I think this is left over from that and trying to determine if it's worth updating all those "CreateObject()" to using a direct reference.

Comment: @Losbear I would update them as you are changing code and/or fixing performance issues.  Unless there's a pressing need an all-out assault is probably not necessary.  Don't fix it if it ain't broke... (just my opinion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to try it both ways and measure it to be sure, but there should not be any significant performance difference if `Class` is a pure COM-object.

Other than that, there's no difference since `objSomething` is typed as a `Project.Class1` in both cases so everything after that is early-bound.

If, however, `Project.Class1` is a .NET object that is com-callable, then you should ALWAYS use `New` because you bypass the COM-interop layer which WILL have a performance impact.  There's no point in creating a .NET class through a COM interop layer.

Comment: Agreed - I figured "CreateObject" has overhead and I thought i read somewhere it loads the library similarly to reflection (or does it use reflection?).  I will measure the difference it takes to load one over the other, but wanted to know if I"m worrying about nothing first :)